# MPICH libraries for quadruple precision not recognised by FFTW3?

Tags: fortran, mpi, gfortran, quadruple-precision

I am converting my parallel double precision fortran code that involves calls to FFTW3 and BLAS-LAPACK packages to parallel quadruple precision.

I have installed FFTW3 for quadruple precision as follows:

```
./configure --enable-quad-precision
```

described in:
http://fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Installation-on-Unix.html#Installation-on-Unix

A sample serial code that calls these libraries works without any issues. I have linked to lquadmath here which tells me that the serial compiler gfortran has that library.

However, to install FFTW3 with parallel libraries requires another tag

```
./configure --enable-mpi --enable-quad-precision
```

When I try this there is an error:

```
configure: error: quad precision is not supported in MPI
```

Following is my install script for mpich-3.2.1:

```
./configure --enable-f90 F77=gfortran FC=gfortran CC=gcc
make 
make install
```

I have tried a mpigather and mpiscatter test using REAL16 datatype (https://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-2.1/mpi21-report-bw/node330.htm) to scatter multiples of pi and it worked alright.

However, FFTW3 does not recognize this.. How do I proceed?
Thankyou for your time.

Comment: You can easily find by Googling that the FFTW manual says *"Long-double precision is supported in MPI, but quad precision (‘fftwq_’) is not due to the lack of MPI support for this type. "* http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/MPI-Files-and-Data-Types.html  So, FFTW does not support quadruple precision in MPI.

Comment: I did see that but is there no way to parallelise quadruple precision then? I'm amazed considering the demand for such an operation

Comment: I am not amazed nor do I think the demand is high.

Comment: https://users.open-mpi.narkive.com/9KHzAb39/ompi-users-mpi-sum-and-mpi-real16-with-mpi-allreduce-in-fortran90 there are references to mpi operations with quad precision here however. How did they achieve that without MPI supporting it..

Comment: It is not enough to test just MPI Scatter and Gather. They will work for anything. Try some reductions, for example. Like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33109040/strange-result-of-mpi-allreduce-for-16-byte-real/34230377

Comment: I have checked and there's a discrepancy as you predicted. I suppose i'll close this question and try to follow the link posted in your comment as there are some suggestions there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186555/discussion-between-sai-and-vladimir-f).